# Currency format with GoogleScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to format cells to Peruvian Nuevo Sol (S/.00.00 - PEN). I'm using `setNumberFormat`.However I've tried several options and I can't get it to work.

This is the line of my script where I'm trying to format the cell:

```
  campaignSheet.getRange(i, 4).setNumberFormat("S/.00.00").setFormula("E"+i+"*3.5");
```

That `i` is there because it's in a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your code able to set other current formats properly? Also, you can speed up your code by eliminating this range loop in favor of a batch operation (see the documentation for `Range::setFormulasR1C1`). `setNumberFormat` will operate equivalently on a single cell vs. an input range.

Comment: @tehhowch thanks, ill read the documentation. About the currency, i made a partial fix by using single quotes first and then double quotes like this: `campaignSheet.getRange(i, 4).setFormula("E"+i+"*3.5").setNumberFormat('"S/." 00.00');`. It didn't exactly change to the currency format I wanted but it looks like it.

Comment: Do you want zeros? Or do you want whatever digit is in the cell? If you want what's already there, just reformatted, change the zeros to `#`. [More on formatting numbers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)

Comment: I wanted the `S/.` symbol that represents Peruvian nuevos soles.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `.setNumberFormat("[$S/.]#,##00.00")`.

Full code would be:

```
campaignSheet.getRange(i, 4).setNumberFormat("[$S/.]#,##00.00").setFormula("E"+i+"*3.5");
```

Of note, you can remove the leading zero for numbers less than 10 (if desired) by using `.setNumberFormat("[$S/.]#,##0.00")` instead.

Hope this helps!